TV series where they plant a chip in the brain of students
I watched these as a kid and have no idea what the series was called... The idea is that students get a chip implant in their brain (the parents don't know this), and when they try to escape from some sort of prison/institute they hear this noise coming from the chip making them have intense pain in their head.
My guess is somewhere around the year 2000 or earlier when they made these.
EDIT: Also there was one student (friend of the main character) who had a peptic ulcer which caused disruptance with the chip or something.
Any idea?

It's not one of the demon headmaster series was it?

@Liath don't think so, the characters look different and it has nothing to do with a chip planted in the brain? There was real surgery involved, don't think it was magic. Just some crazy medics doing stuff to students I think

This is from The Outer Limits episode titled Straight and Narrow. IMDb's synopsis reads:

Rusty Dotson is not too keen when his mother enrolls him in a private school. The residential academy for boys have a long history of turning troubled boys around many of whom have gone on to outstanding careers. Rusty is rebellious to say the least and doesn't fall into what everyone refers to as "the program". He finds another student who hasn't been brainwashed, Charlie Walters, and they learn that they have had computer chips implanted in their brains. When Rusty realizes the students are being programmed as killers, he is determined to stop them.

